# Weird thing happening with code on SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

hopefully someone can provide some insight into this..

I have an SSIS package that runs a SQL command from variable to select data from a table and input it onto a STG table on another server. It's a pretty straight forward query, just a

```
select column1, column2, column3, column4 
from table 
where createddate >= the start of today
```

Lately this query has started hanging and not running at all. I checked the wait and all it says under wait_resource is "43:1:476281".

The weird thing is, if I take the query it is executing and run it myself on the server it not only brings data back instantly, but it seems to "unblock" the SSIS package query and allows it to finish running.

Has anyone heard of this happening and could possibly explain why? I'd appreciate any help!

Ran query myself, this worked but only then did the SSIS query run

SSIS query to run just as quick as me running it in management studio

Comment: The wait resource looks to be a page. What is the wait type?

Comment: Its PAGEIOLATCH_SH

Comment: Does the page resource change while the package query runs? The latch should be short-lived.

Comment: smells like a problem with parameter sniffing and bad execution plans -try to add the option(recompile) hint to your SSIS query

Comment: No the resource stays the same. I will ad the option(recompile) and see if this fixes it

Comment: Hi @Jess8766 ensure you did not overlook any other locks, it is likely due to an implicit transaction and you run multiple inserts or updates to the same table.